# Wave function continuity between plane wave and helical wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

Suppose an interface with the wave function of left side a plane wave $A e^{ik_1x}$, and the right side a helical wave $Be^{ik_2x}e^{im\theta}$, $m \ne 0$ is the orbital angular momentum and $\theta$ the azimuthal angle. Can this setup meet the wave function continuity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In a birefringent material, one linear polarization could have a different index of refraction than the other. This would give one polarization a different wavelength than the other. After traveling a certain distance, the phase difference between the polarizations will become $90^o$. This is the condition for circular polarization.

Comment: I have two more questions. 1. There needs to be a transition (certain distance) between the linear polarization and circular polarization. So, at the very interface, the plane wave and the helical wave are not directly touching with each other. 2. Both linear polarization and circular polarization are for spin angular momentum, how about orbital angular momentum (twisted light) as what I am considering here?

Answer (score 0):

At the interface, the functions of the two fields existing on either side of the interface must be exactly the same. That is the boundary condition for EM fields that must be satisfied.

One way to see that these two functions are not the same is the following: A propagating beam with nonzero orbital angular momentum (OAM) due to a helical phase must have a zero along its propagation axis, otherwise it cannot satisfy Maxwell's equations. A plane wave does not have such a zero. Another thing that is different is the phase of the two functions. Therefore, these two functions cannot satisfy the boundary condition.

If the function on the side with the plane wave can become a superposition of plane waves, then it would be possible to satisfy the boundary condition. All one needs to do is to compute the Fourier transform of the beam with nonzero OAM to see what the spectrum of plane waves is that would satisfy the boundary condition.

---

About the reason for the zero: when you look at the helical function with $m=1$ for example, so that we get $\exp(i\phi)$ and we restrict it to the line where $y=0$ then the resulting function of $x$ is the sign function: $\sigma(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and $\sigma(x)=1$ for $x>0$. At $x=0$ the function is undefined, but more importantly the derivative of the function is divergent (infinite). This is not allowed for a propagating electromagnetic field. All derivatives of the electromagnetic field must be finite. The way nature solves this problem is to produce a null at the origin of the helical phase function because when the function goes to zero it produces the necessary slope that will invert the sign of the function while maintaining a finite derivative. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain more about why helical wave must have a zero whereas plane wave does not? What's the meaning of "zero" here?